# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade error

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest Ubuntu release, and I want to test Unity 8. When I executed:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the,

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

I have got the following error:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_atareao_atareao_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key A3D8A366869FE2DC5FFD79C36A9653F936FD5529 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_docky-core_stable_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 53BD7760A5A09E78FC8649D9608BF7B93528AE20 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_nilarimogard_webupd8_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 1DB29AFFF6C70907B57AA31F531EE72F4C9D234C (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_apps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4FA44A478284A18C1BA4A9CAD530E028F59EAE4D (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_rvm_smplayer_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key E23A3C5344AE497C2FEE7B0BA7E13D78E4A4F4F4 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_team-xbmc_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 189701DA570C56B9488EF60A6D975C4791E7EE5E (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_teejee2008_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 1B32B87ABAEE357218F6B48CB5B116B72D0F61F0 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_webdesigner_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 (weak digest)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release, which is considered strong enough for security purposes
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_webdesigner_deb_dists_stable_Release, which is considered strong enough for security purposes
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: There is no upgrade path to 16.04 yet.

Comment: We don't support 16.04 questions here yet until it gets finally officially released in April.

Comment: bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1558331

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely upgrade to 16.04 as described ahead, but it's advisable to disable any 3rd party repository while upgrading to a new version of OS. Also to upgrade a version, the command is 'sudo do-release-upgrade -d' where -d is used as it's still under development, to be used only after update and dist-upgrade commands. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already installed the 16.04 version. I'm now trying to to an upgrade in order to install Unity 8.

Comment: Only by these commands:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir:

Comment: the error appears each time I execute this command.